# npm run android No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, android-ndk

HELP!!... I can't run a newly generated react native app with `npm run android`, I already tried the following: `/gradlew clean`, made sure the emulator is up and running, I also tried to install the ndk, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to select it.

```
 ✘ dio@pop-os  ~/Documents/Code/Beex-Travel/beexmobile   developing  npm run android

> beexmobile@0.0.1 android /home/dio/Documents/Code/Beex-Travel/beexmobile
> react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1096 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
25 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 23 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! beexmobile@0.0.1 android: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the beexmobile@0.0.1 android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dio/.npm/_logs/2021-03-15T08_03_34_370Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Android NDK. There should be clear instructions how to do this for your platform. Then put the directory where you have the executables that have the fine name starting with ’arm-linux-androideabi’ in your PATH. Make sure  you can run ’arm-linux-androideabi-gcc’ or any other thing you find in the ’bin’ directory. Then try and see if your ’npm’ build command proceeds further.